# Post issue after bios update, forced restart helps

Tags: boot, motherboard, unresponsive

Having booting issue after a Bios update. I can access Bios, Windows 10, Linux Manjaro but it requires forced restarts.
The problem is black screen just before Bios prompt, everything has power but cpu fan and gpu not spinning. When forcing a restart the fans spinning and I can access Bios etc. Before I did the update I put the motherboard on its default settings.
Is it safe to downgrade the bios?

With no beeping, no warnings of any kind I having trouble solving this issue.

Specs:
Asus Prime x370 Pro Bios version 6042
Ryzen 5 3600
32GB RAM at 3000mhz

Thanks for the suggestions, I downloaded the Bios from Asus website. Can't find anything about it not be compatible. Windows and Manjaro works fine. Had trouble with Grub after Bios update but a reinstall fixed that. All other hardware should be up to date.

Comment: Did you get certified BIOS from the computer manufacturer?  Is Manjaro compatible with this BIOS update.

Comment: (1) Did you also reset the BIOS settings **after** the BIOS upgrade?  (2)  You also should upgrade the drivers for system hardware. (3) Check the reboot problems using and solving only one OS. Mixing both will make the interpretation of the states very difficult. // Please update your question with the structured behavior using consequently only one of the OS. Then in a second step (after a not counted reboot) with the other OS.

Comment: If no solution is found, I would suggest to return to the BIOS version that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Seems DCOP is the culprit, boots just fine in default mode and in 2400MHz. So problem solved for now, thanks once again.